# C# Get excel macros name

Tags: c#, vba, excel

How to get list of macros names that's displayed in tab "Developer" by button "macros"? I found some solution (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ef1de29a-81c7-424a-b7ab-f85286a1d8de/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-macros-in-an-excel-workbook?forum=vsto), but it's work with button "Visual basic" in same tab. Maybe we can extract macros names from there?

Answer (score 0):

"*Maybe we can extract macros names from there?*"
Obviously **no, you can't.**

And the answer in your link already said this "*As far as I know, there is no a property which can be used to get the names of macros.*".
So there is no built-in way to extract them.

The only way I can imagine is parsing all the code and looking for `Function` and `Sub` to collect their names. But this can be cumbersome.

Maybe studying the source code of the [Rubberduck AddIn at GitHub](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) can help. I know that such a parsing is implemented there (in C# aswell) as they need it to generate a list of functions/procedures too, so maybe this can help you getting an idea how to implement this.